# Compound Varnish URL filtering with query params

Tags: varnish

I have a WordPress instance with Varnish in front in which I have blocked access to `wp-login.php` via VCL by using:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    # block outside access to login
    if (req.url ~ "wp-admin" && !client.ip ~ white_list) {
        return (synth(404, "Page not found"));
    }
 }
```

For reference, `white_list` is just an included file with a list of white-listed IPs. To this point, this has worked very well.

My client has recently requested use of WordPress protected pages for a pseudo password protected page. I discovered that this method uses `/wp-login.php?action=postpass` to validate the password. Due to my whitelist block of `wp-login.php` some (not all, which is weird) requests come back as 404.

This means that all requests to `/wp-login.php?action=postpass` should be passed through and all requests to `wp-login.php` in which the requesting IP does not match the `white_list` should be denied. What I started with was:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    # allow wp protected pages
    if (req.url ~ "wp-login" && req.url ~ "\?action\=postpass$") {
      return(pass);
    } else if (req.url ~ "wp-(admin|login)" && !client.ip ~ white_list) {
       return(synth(404, "Page not found"));
    }
}
```

This looks to me like it should work, but doesn't. As is, this rule allows all access to `wp-login.php` regardless of the `white_list`. I've temporarily removed `&& !client.ip ~ white_list` in order to keep the block up, but I'm stumped on why that piece of the conditional would eval to false when it has worked before.

Comment: Do you have to use varnish for cache? you can try nuster, https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster, easily achieve your requirements